# useRef value not persisting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, use-ref

I am building a weather app where i have an index page which displays a bunch of cards for each hour. I have a value (whether it is AM or PM) which i am storing in a useref and passing it to child component. When some condition is met an onChange function is called from the child (this function exist in the parent)and changes the value of the useref but the value is not changing in the child. The bunch of cards are displayed by mapping through them so i am expecting if the useref value is changed in the parent the next card would get the changed value but this is not happening. Am i using useref wrong?
index.js

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import WeatherCard from '../components/WeatherCard'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { PropsType } from '../types'

const Home: NextPage<PropsType> = (props) => {

  const [time,setTime]=useState(new Date());
  const timeFormatRef=React.useRef(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', 
                    {hour: 'numeric', hour12: true }).split(' ')[1]) as any;
  
  const onTimeFormatChange=()=>{
    if(timeFormatRef.current==='AM')  
      timeFormatRef.current='PM' 
    else 
      timeFormatRef.current='AM';
  }
  
  return (
    <div className=>
      <main>
         {determineWeatherCardsArr().map((el,index)=>{
           return <motion.div>
                    <WeatherCard key={index} weather={el.weather} 
                                temp={el.temp} index={index} 
                                time={time} ref={timeFormatRef} 
                               onTimeFormatChange= {onTimeFormatChange}/>
                   </motion.div>})
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

WeatherCard.js

```
import Image from "next/image";

const WeatherCard:React.forwardref=(props,ref)=>{

    const determineHour=(time:Date):string=>{
        
        let amPmTimeArr=time.toLocaleString('en-US', 
                   { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true }).split(' ');
        let hour
        [hour]=[...amPmTimeArr]
        
        if(+hour+props.index>=12){
            hour=(+hour+props.index)%12;
        
            if(+hour===0){
               props.onTimeFormatChange();//changing the useref here 
               
            }
            
            return hour+ref.current;
        }
        else{
            hour=+hour+props.index
            return hour+ref.current;
        }
         
    }

    let cardTitle=determineHour(props.time)
    return(
        <div className="">
            <h3 className="">{cardTitle}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React does not 'react' to ref values changes so your child component will not be rerendered if the ref value changes. Use a state variable to achieve that

Comment: i am rendering the component multiple times using map and i am changing the ref value in the parent and forwarding it to the children so the next child should have the updated ref value but it is not. useState is causing an infinite loop so i am looking for a different solution

Comment: @H.b exactly what this answer says. Even if your component is referencing the ref and it now contains the correct value (in JS), React does not know it needs to re-render your child component. You shouldn't be using a ref for this. Maybe you mean to use Context, if your intent is to prevent prop drilling. React will re-render on context changes. If you really want to use your current system, you can force a re-render on children by setting any state (even if it does nothing), or you can use what React was built to do, and use props/context/state that informs react of a needed re-render.

Comment: @H.b you need to solve the issue with the state var or populate the 24 hours fixed starting at the time when the component mounts

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita  but if render the cards by mapping thru an array and on one of the cards the value of the ref is updated by calling the onChange function passed through props should i not get the updated value of the ref in the next card??? I just want to understand this

Comment: @H.b the ref value will be updated after the .map(), react wont re-render the component nor its children so the rendered inside map will never see the change made in the ref val

Comment: @H.b no, because that next card isn't rendering either. It would have the updated value in the next render.

Comment: @H.b https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-jang-8d6e95?file=/src/App.js play with this to understand. Refs are just persistent objects in memory, like a global variable, except scoped to the component that created it. You can even change the ref's value via the console and see the value update, if you wanted when you render. While this illustrates what a ref is, you should still not be using it like this because it's an anti pattern. Everyone will be confused looking at it.

Comment: so there are like 48 cards so i dont want to use useState or context because i will have to change it after every 12 cards so I am thinking of using local storage. is that ok?

Comment: What you should do, is not bake in logic like that into the cards. Create React components that know how to render given **data** (props). Generate the data beforehand separately.